# How to use QueryString

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, query-string, asp.net-mvc-routing

How can I have different URL ids like www.somewebsite.com/index?theidentifier=34 only in ASP.NET MVC not Webforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for what purpose?  Just to access the value?  All querystring values can be routed to params in the action method like:

```
public ActionResult index(int? theidentifier)
{
   //process value
}
```

Or, you can use the QueryString collection as mentioned above, I think it's via this.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle your routing in ASP.NET MVC, then you can open Global.asax and add calling of routes.MapRoute in RegisterRoutes method.

The default routing configuration is {controller}/{action}/{id} => ex:
http://localhost/Home/Index/3 , controller = HomeController, Action=About, id=3.

You may add something like :

routes.MapRoute(
"NewRoute", // Route name
"Index/{id}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index",id=1 } // Parameter defaults
);

so http://localhost/Index/3 will be accepted

Remember to add these code above the default route configuration, because ASP.NET will search for the first matching route